EFI Boot, occur error message: Command Error Status: Not Found
（Emulex or Qlogic HBA） In legacy mode, the command can be executed to start, but in uefi mode, the command cannot be executed. But my OS boot mode is efi, I don't know why.

legacy:
enter image description here

efi:
enter image description here



CSM -> UEFI
PCIe device -> other -> UEFI
【can't boot】
CSM-> Leacy & UEFI
PCIe device -> other -> UEFI
【can't boot】
CSM-> Leacy & UEFI
PCIe device -> other -> Legacy
【can boot】
CSM-> Legacy
PCIe device -> other -> Legacy
【can boot】
CSM-> UEFI
PCIe device -> other -> Legacy
【can boot】
